# Curvature of a semi-log plot

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, graphing-functions, curvature

I have the function:
$$y=\frac{x(2-x)}{2(1-x)}$$

The semilog plot of this shows a strong knee and a strong elbow feature:

[image: Semilog plot]

So how do I find where these are?

I have been using this for curvature:

$$\kappa=\frac{y^{\prime\prime}}{(1+y^{\prime 2})^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$

But I'm not getting sensible answers ... is there a better way? How should I account for the semilog plotting? Take the log of the function?

Comment: This is a log-lin plot, or $\log y$ vs $x$. If you substitute $u = \log(y)$ and plot $u$ vs $x$ on a linear scale you get the same plot. This suggests looking the curvature of the function $u(x) = \log(y(x))$. You really only want to solve $u''(x) = 0$ for the turning points

Comment: I get this for the second derivative of ln(y(x)): $-\dfrac{x^4-4x^3+10x^2-12x+4}{\left(x-2\right)^2\left(x-1\right)^2x^2}$ and it has a root at 0.514 which isn't what the graph suggests

Comment: Well, that's actually where the turning point is. The "bends" are where the slope rapidly increases. I'm not sure if you can put a value on that

Comment: I suppose one way you an estimate those points is to fit a straight line around that turning point, an compute the function's deviation from that line. You can then put a lower bound on that error, and find out where the error is "large enough"

Comment: Just so you know, this is all subjective. As far the function knows, it is only increasing. The "bends" look sharp only because you scale the graph that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been pointed out above, the curvature is an artefact of the plot (scaling) parameters and not a fundamental result.